# Assignment Operator Overloading and Self Assignment

Tags: c++

I've tried to understand Why in '=' overloading I have to check for self Assignment .I think i know the answer , it's because endless loop but I can't understand why the loop is started ?.

Example :

```
Point p1(3,5);
p1 = p1 ;
```

Comment: Where's the overloaded operator?

Comment: Why would self assignment cause an endless loop?

Comment: There *might* be a loop, but there are also other reasons, like not being able to copy some types of data over itself or for efficiency. There's really no one correct answer for this, except "it depends" and "don't do it".

Comment: Your example is not sufficient. Why dont you write a assignemt operator (once without and once with check for selfassignment) then one could dicuss the difference.

Comment: We guard against self assignment not because it will cause a loop, but because we don't want to free resources that we will then use to assign to our-self with.

Comment: It is not always *necessary* to check for self-assignment.   The copy-and-swap idiom provides one way to avoid such a check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about endless recursion, at least not usually. The frequent issue with self-assignment is when you try to destroy a resource you own before copying the other object's one: if this object is actually the same, the resource is lost.

```
struct Object {
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> _resource;

    Object &operator = (Object const &other) {
        _resource = nullptr;                // Destroy "my" resource
        _resource = clone(other._resource); // Nothing to clone anymore...
    }
};
```

The example is contrived: no one would first reset a pointer, *then* assign it. But this pattern popped up a lot in older C++, and is the origin of the "beware of self-assignment" advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no loop. What can happen is when you have a resource like some allocated memory.

If you have a shared pointer on some data. During the assignment, the first thing you do is de allocate your local data. Then you replace it with the data from the other object. If they are the same, then you lost your resource.

The solution is then to check self assignments.